# copy values one database to another database using trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two databases in **mysql** server. Both databases are localhost ( same server).
Database names are `DB1` , `DB2`. and both database has table name called users.

Table columns are **id , name , email**.

Whenever i add a new data in `DB1` same data should get add into another database `DB2` in users table.

```
INSERT INTO DB1.users (id, name, email) VALUES ('', 'raj', 'raj@gmail.com');
```

If Same database means i could write **Trigger** Query to perform this operation. one database to another database trigger is not working. How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can u check that aproach:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewTrigger ON [users]
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO DB2.[users] (id, name, email)
SELECT id, name, email
FROM inserted
```

Comment: only data will moves else primary keys and sp, views any other doesn't copy's

Comment: @Arockiaraj , check now, i changed from DB1 to DB2, maybe it was mistake.

Comment: @Arockiaraj u got primary keys in that other table? Allowing to insert values? WIth incrementation/Identity? U should remove Identity and alow Insertion on that ID field in other database.